# Parametric 12-deg and 14-deg equations with group $PGL(2,11)$ and $PGL(2,13)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-curves

We have,

$$x^{12} - a x^{11} - 33x^8 + 22a x^7 - 11a^2 x^6 + 363x^4 - 121a x^3 + 121a^2x^2 - 23a^3x - 11^3 + a^4=0$$

$$x^{12} - a x^{11} - 11a x^9 - 44a x^7 - 88a x^5 - 88a x^3 - 32a x - a^2=0$$

$$x^{14} - a x^{13} - 26b x^{10} + 65b^2 x^6 + 13a b^2 x^5 - 52b^3x^2 - 12a b^3 x - a^2b^3 = 0$$

with discriminants,

$$D_{12(1)}= -11^{11}a^{24}(a^4 + 12^4)^2(a^4 + 4^4)^5$$

$$D_{12(2)} = -11^{11}a^{12} (a^2 + 1)^2(a^2 + 4^6)^2(a^2 + 4^3)^6$$

$$D_{14}=13^{13}a^2 b^{36}(a^4 + 12^4b)^2(a^4 + 4^4b)^7$$

**Questions:**

1. Is the Galois group of the three equations $PGL(2,11),\; PGL(2,11),\; PGL(2,13)$, respectively?
2. Considering how similar are the discriminants of the first and the third, is there a connection between them, i.e. is there a systematic way to generate parametric equations with Galois group $PGL(2,n)$?